# For pytorch RNN model, can we inference the input by its output results?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, inference

all,

I wonder, torch.nn.rnn(~). If I know the final output, does it possible, I could inference its input value? For example:

```
myrnn = nn.RNN(4, 2, 1, batch_first=True)
expected_out, hidden = myrnn(input)
expected_out:  tensor([[[-0.7773, -0.2031]],

    [[-0.4129, -0.1802]],

    [[ 0.0599, -0.0151]],

    [[-0.9273,  0.2683]],

    [[ 0.6161,  0.5412]]])
```

Thank you so mcuh!!!

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is theoretically impossible

Neural networks in general represent functions that are impossible to inverse as they are not guaranteed to be [byjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) regardless of the underlying architecture.

This means that neither rnn nor any other neural network are invertible.